# My female cat is in heat and is constantly meowing loudly. We are unable to sleep. Help

Tags: cats, breeding

My female cat is 6 months old. This is her first heat. Vet has confirmed it as heat.

She is constantly shouting loudly in a harsh voice. We are unable to sleep for the last two days.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to fix this is to get her spayed, may need to buy some earplugs in the meantime and put her a room furthest from where you sleep.

I will also add some people will stimulate them with a Qtip, since they are induced ovulators it will end the cycle. I would have a veterinarian show you the first time around if you don't want to spay her.

Comment: Spaying is a good option but not at this time. I also wish to have some kitten at some time.

Comment: I was  watching in youtube about some pheromone releasers which soothes cat. Also hot water pack helps. Playing with them, massaging their back spine, giving them doll male cat, all of which helps

Comment: You might be thinking of Feliway? The rest sounds a bit like very short term solutions. They still have the urge because of their hormones - massages won't really help, she'll still be howling all night. No harm in trying though.